# Exception when using @Scheduled spring annotation (Cannot find class [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor])

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have created a scheduled job using a `@Scheduled` annotation.
It looks like this:

```
package example.tools.rr; 

public class RequestProcessorJob {
    private RequestService requestService;
    ...
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void process() {
         ...
    }

    public RequestService getRequestService() { return requestService; }

    public void setRequestService(RequestService requestService) { this.requestService = requestService; }

}
```

I've put it inside a bundle A, so I can use this class in other bundles. I imported it inside bundle B. B's blueprint.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:cm="http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/schema/blueprint-compendium"
  xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
              http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/schema/blueprint-compendium http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/schema/blueprint-compendium/gemini-blueprint-compendium.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
              ">
  ... 

  <bean id="handsetService" class="example.handset.impl.HandsetServiceImpl">
    ...
  </bean>

  <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" />
  <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1" />
  <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"
                          scheduler="taskScheduler" />

  <bean class="example.tools.rr.RequestProcessorJob">
    <cm:managed-properties persistent-id="example.handset.processing"
                           autowire-on-update="true" />
    <property name="requestService" ref="handsetService" />
  </bean>

</blueprint>
```

When I install the bundle (inside Apache Felix) a following exception is thrown:

```
Unable to create application context for [example.handset], unsatisfied dependencies:
none
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] for bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' defined in null; nested
exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor not found from bundle [example.handset]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:897) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:325) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:290) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:137) ~[na:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor not found from bundle [example.handset]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:101) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:155) ~[na:na]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254) ~[na:na]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor not found by example.handset [443]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1499) ~[felix.jar:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
~[felix.jar:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1882) ~[felix.jar:na]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1793) ~[felix.jar:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:929) ~[felix.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:97) ~[na:na]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
```

if I add an empty class which just has a `@Scheduled` annotation inside the bundle B, everything works fine and the **RequestProcessorJob** is scheduled properly (the empty class is not used, but it makes the error not occur).

```
public class MockJob {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void process() { }
}
```

I've tried to include the module A inside of B in `pom.xml` as `<scope>provided</scope>` as well as `<scope>compile</scope>`, the result is the same.

Having a reduntant class to make it work doesn't really sounds like a solution. Do You have any ideas about this? Is this a bug, or maybe somehow it was supposed to work so strangely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was just missing org.springframework.scheduling.annotation in <Import-Package> section in pom.xml. Quite obvious after all, but the behaviour of spring is still weird here.